# How to write abstract and derived Gradle Groovy Tasks?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have a few questions how I can write maintainable Groovy Gradle tasks:

- How can I mark a task as 'abstract', so that are tasks unable to run from the commandline, which require an derived implementation?
- How can I derive a task?
- How can I 'encapsulate' variables? (which are preferable not accesible outside the (parent)task).

Eg in this pseudo gradle script, I expect only `runnableTask` to be executable, which result in running `someTask` with `param = "TEST"` and `param2 = "SOMETHINGELSE"`

What is doable of this?

```
***abstract*** task someTask(type: com.bla.ATask) {
    param=someVar1
    param2=someVar2
}

***abstract*** task derivedTESTTask(***extends*** someTask) {
    someVar1="TEST"
}

task runnableTask(***extends**** derivedTESTTask) { 
    someVar2="SOMETHINGELSE"
}
```

Comment: You mix up task types (classes) and tasks (instances). You can't derive an instance from another instance, you can just derive a class from another class and then create an instance of that derived class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create exactly abstract task with parameters you can create class, extends it from `DefaultTask` and define your parameters:

```
abstract class AdsTask extends DefaultTask {

  @Input
  def param1

  @Input
  def param2
}
```

Then you need create its implementation:

```
class ConcreteTask extends AdsTask {
  @TaskAction
  void anyNameMethod() {
    // your code
    println "Params $param1 $param2"
  }
}
```

And then create task this concrete values for these params:

```
task task1(type: ConcreteTask) {
  param1="TEST"
  param2="SOMETHINGELSE"
}
```

**But you can do simpler:**

```
class ConcreteTask extends DefaultTask {

  @Input
  def param1

  @Input
  def param2

  @TaskAction
  void anyNameMethod() {
    // your code
    println "Params $param1 $param2"
  }
}

task task1(type: ConcreteTask) {
  param1="TEST"
  param2="SOMETHINGELSE"
}
```